# Is it safe to access non-const object through const lvalue?

Tags: c, constants, language-lawyer

The `6.5(p7)` states this:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types:88)
>
> — a type compatible the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the
>   signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>   object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to
>   a qualified version of the effective type of the object,

Taking a look at `6.7.3(p10)`:

> For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the
>   identically qualified version of a compatible type;

So `double` and `const double` are not compatible because their type qualifiers are not the same.

Now I assumed that **signed or unsigned type** mean **signed or unsigned integer type** as defined it `6.2.5(p4)` and `6.2.5(p6)` correspondingly since `6.2.5` does not define **signed type** by itself.

Now consider the following code:

```
void print_double(const double d){
    printf("d = %lf\n", d);
}

int main(int args, const char *argv[]){
    double d = 10.2;
    print_double(d);
}
```

Now I try to apply `6.5 (p7)`:

I. `a type compatible the effective type of the object`

No, `const double` and `double` are not compatible.

II. `a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object`

No, qualified version of `const double` will make it even more qualified then `const double`

III/IV.

No, `double` is not a signed or unsigned integer type.

This judgement seems faulty because it should be ok to access non-const object via const-qualified lvalue. But I cannot derive that from `6.5(p7)`.

Comment: @StoryTeller Agree, I provided very bad example. But what if we declare `extern const double` then later define it as just `double`? I edited the example.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, since it's no longer about aliasing. It's about matching declarations to definitions, another thing entirely.

Comment: It must be read as *"a qualified version of (a type compatible with the effective type of the object)"*, not  as *"(a qualified version of a type) compatible with the effective type of the object"*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now consider the following code:
>
> ```
> void print_double(const double d){
>     printf("d = %lf\n", d);
> }
>
> int main(int args, const char *argv[]){
>     double d = 10.2;
>     print_double(d);
> }
> ```

Your code doesn't do any aliasing. The `d` in main and the `d` in `print_double` are *distinct* objects, since arguments are always passed by value. But if we were to "fix" the example:

```
void print_double(const double *pd){
    printf("d = %lf\n", *pd);
}

int main(int args, const char *argv[]){
    double d = 10.2;
    print_double(&d);
}
```

It's still well-defined. `*pd` is an lvalue of type `const double`. `const double` is a qualified version of `double`. All types are compatible with themselves (trivially). So the second bullet holds and this aliasing is valid.

Comment: So the second bullet can be reinterpreted as "If we discard some qualifiers from the type of an lvalue we are trying to access the object we should get compatible types"?

Comment: @SomeName - Yes, that's one way to look at it, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

If two pointers (lvalue accesses) may *alias* is a different matter than if they point at *compatible types*. The part you quote is about pointer aliasing (aka "the strict aliasing rule"), which for a reason is written as:

> - a type compatible the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object

Which means exactly that a const-qualified object may *alias* a non-qualified object, even though they are not compatible types. Example:

```
void f (const int* a, int* b);
```

`a` might point at the same data as `b`. The compiler is not free to assume that they point at separate objects.

But this doesn't even apply to your case, since you pass the parameter by value and create a local copy. Aliasing would apply if your example was this:

```
double a = 10.2;

int main(int args, const char *argv[]){
    print_double(&a);
}

void print_double(const double* b){
    printf("d = %lf\n", b);
}
```

Where the parameter `b` is a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object (`double`). The compiler may therefore not assume that `b` does not point at the global variable `a`.

---

Regarding compatibility:

Whenever you copy an object either through assignment `=` or by passing it as parameter to a function, the rules of simple assignment kick in. 6.5.16.1 allows this:

> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering
>     the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are
>     pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed
>     to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;

Meaning `int* a; const int* b = a;` is fine but `const int* a; int* b = a;` is a constraint violation. The very same rules applies during parameter passing, see 6.9.1/10:

> On entry to the function, the size expressions of each variably modified parameter are
>   evaluated and the value of each argument expression is converted to the type of the
>   corresponding parameter as if by assignment.

What happens in your case is that the value of `d` in the caller is copied into a new variable of type `const double`. This is allowed per the rule of simple assignment and you create a new variable - all is well.